# Swift 4 delegate is not working with tabbar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, protocols

I have a tabbar view controller with 4 views and I had set a protocol on the 4th view and made the 1st view conform to this protocol. When I call the delegate method from the 4th view it is not working and there is no segue between 1st and 4th view controllers.

I have defined my protocol 
    and set `weak var delegate: delegateProtocol?`
    then in the first view controller I did the following

```
class VC1: delegateProtocol {
    viewdidLoad(){
    var vc4 = VC4()
    VC4.delegate = self
  }
```

This is a snippet of the 4th view controller

```
protocol SettingsDelegate: class {
    func locationDidSet(location: CLLocation)
}


class VC4: UIViewController {


  weak var delegate: SettingsDelegate?
 let controller = LocationPickerViewController()
 let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
 present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  controller.completion = { location in
                self.location = location?.title ?? "Not found"
                defaults.set(location: location!.location, forKey: "location")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.delegate?.locationDidSet(location: location!.location)
            }
```

and this is the snippet from the 1st ViewController

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, SettingsDelegate {
    func locationDidSet(location: CLLocation) {
        print(location.coordinate.latitude)
    }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        settingVC = SettingsVC()
        settingVC?.delegate = self
}
}
```

Comment: Be aware that in a storyboard based environment the default initializer `SettingsVC()` never returns the instance designed in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MainVC`'s `viewDidLoad` you are creating a new `SettingsVC` instance and assigning `self` to that instance's property. Not to the actual forth view controller of the tab bar controller.

Get the fourth view controller instance from the `tabBarController?.viewControllers` array and assign `self` to its `delegate` property

//MainVC

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  if let settingVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is SettingsVC }) as? SettingsVC {
    settingVC.delegate = self
  }
}
```

If the view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

//Update

```
if let settingsNavVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is UINavigationController }) as? UINavigationController, 
    let settingsVC = settingsNavVC.rootViewController as? SettingsVC {
        settingsVC.delegate = self
}
```